# How to remove "Open Web Part Page in maintenance view" when editing the wiki page properties

Tags: development, page-layout, wiki-pages, edit-form, enterprise-wiki

I am working on an Enterprisewiki site collection inside SP 2013, and currently when contributor users edit the wiki page properties by going to "Page Option >> Edit Properties" , then will find the following link, which sound strange :-

[image]

so can anyone advice what is the purpose of this link and how i can remove it ?

Answer (score 1):

This message will show when we edit the properties of a page no matter which library / wikis we upload it to, it seems to be by design.

If you have any webpart on the page, once you click on it, it will give you control to perform maintenance on the webpart `i.e. Close, Reset. Delete etc`.
[image]

To remove that i think you need to Customized the EditForm.aspx.

Comment: i do not have any web part on the wiki pages , except a web part to handle the redirect at the home page. so if there is not any web part on the wiki age , so the links to reset,delete,etc is meaningless is this correct ?

Comment: i just put the half of the page, if you dont have any webpart on the page then after clicking on the link you will get this text "
There are currently no Web Parts associated with any Web Part Zones on this page. Web Parts added to the page outside of a Web Part Zone will not appear in this list."

Comment: the strange thing is that contributor users inside our enterprise wiki  can not add web parts to the pages and they will get an error that they do not have the permission to add web parts. but from the "Open Web Part Page in maintenance view" link inside the Page Properties , they can delete the web part.. so strange how SP do not allow contribute users to add web parts to the wiki pages , but they allow them to remove them from the pages !!!

Comment: now i edit the Editform and i added the following code snippet to hide the link using javascript "$('#ctl00_ctl40_g_6c7d849e_da6b_4138_be9f_b99bde542065_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_WebPartMaintenancePageLink').hide();" and it worked well ,, but still users can manually navigate to the URL ,, although it will be hard to know it ... what do u think ?

Comment: that's true, if user know about the url then he can directly go their. i think this is ok, you cant control everything.if you compeletly remove this page from the farm then it will impact on all other non wiki pages.

Comment: but how come SP by defualt do not allow contributor users to add web parts to pages due to permission,, but they can remove the web parts from the above link? i think this is a bug in SP ? what do u think ?

Comment: if you check the permission levels you will see if add webpart or delete webpart allowed or not.

Comment: One personal comment, i saw you open couple of questions but you little hesitant to at least give the up vote who respond as answer...up vote always encourage contributor...i hope you understand and dont mind it.

Comment: as i mentioned Contributor users are not able to add WebParts , so if contributor user edit a wiki page->inert-->web part he will get an error that he do not have the permission to add web parts. but at the same time contributor user can click on the above link and remove the added web part,, did u get my point ?

Comment: yes sir, i get that points. i recommending check the permission levels  site settings > site permission > from ribbon click on permission level....here you will see what option selected

Comment: the contribute permission allow to add/edit/delete personal web part. but in my case i added a web part to allow meta data navigation, and when contributor user try to add this web part on a wiki page , he will get an error that he do not have the required permission,,, but the contributor user can remove this web part using the above link ..... this what is confusing me ... and i think it is a bug in SP ... i mean Contributor user is able to delete a web part he do not have the permission to add ..

Comment: looks like a bug, but i have to test this.